# failed to install my own perl module(pm file)

Tags: perl, module

I have made my own perl modules(pm files),named test.pm

```
package test;
use Exporter;
use strict;
use File::Basename qw(basename dirname);
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use FindBin qw($Bin $Script);
BEGIN {
        our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
        our @EXPORT = qw(mkdirOrDie);
        our $VERSION = 1.0;
}

sub mkdirOrDie
{
    my ($dir) = @_ ;
    if(!-d $dir){
        make_path($dir);
        $dir=abs_path($dir);
#       timeLog("Directory Created: $dir");
    }
}
```

and I tried to install this module as follows,

```
h2xs -AX -n  test

perl Makefile.PL
make
make install
```

there is no error,and I copy the `test.pm` to `/usr/lib64/perl5/5.10.0/`,but when i call sub function using test, an error has occurred,

```
Undefined subroutine &main::mkdirOrDie called at /to/my/path/main.pl line 92
```

is there something i ignored?

Comment: That's not a very smart name. It might clash with other stuff. Also note that modules should always start with capital letters. Small letter packages are meant to be pragmas.

Comment: @simbabque +1 ,Thank you for your kindness, I will pay attention to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear at which point things started to go wrong for you.

Firstly, `test.pm` is a bad name for a Perl module. Perl modules should have names that begin with upper case letters (and [`Test.pm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test) is already taken).

You should run `h2xs` **before** writing your code - as it generates a module skeleton for you fill in. I hope it hasn't overwritten your code with an almost empty file! It's also worth noting that most people stopped using `h2xs` many years ago. These days we have tools like [Module::Starter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Starter).

Then, running, `make install` (which you need to do with root permissions - so usually with `sudo`) is what installs your module into the system libraries. There should be no need to run that `cp` command afterwards.

As for why your code doesn't find the module, there are many possible reasons. Are you using Perl 5.10 or do you have other Perl versions installed? What does the code look like that you are trying to use? Does test.pm still include the code you think it does?

Need more information to be much help here.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I found there are several libraries in the system, I solve it just by adding `use lib "/usr/lib64/perl5/5.10.0/"`

Comment: @JunhuiLi: That sounds like a bit of a sticking-plaster fix. You would be better advised to address the many other issues in my post.